# How to list all articles from an author Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I try to find all the articles associated to an author, even those reallocated to another author in the meantime.
Have you any ideas about that ?
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's simple. First get all the users with `author` role and then pass those user_ids to `WP_Query()`.

To get `user_ids`:

```
function author_ids_by_role() {
    $user_ids = get_users(array('role' => 'author' ,'fields' => 'ID'));
    return $user_ids;
}
```

Now, in `WP_Query()`:

```
$user_ids = author_ids_by_role();
$args = array(
    "posts_per_page"  => 10,
    "post_type"       => "post",
    "author__in"      => $user_ids
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```